# TRIM SQL Search Parmeter

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2008

I need to trim a search parameter so that when a number is entered it will trim the results so that there are no leading or tailing blank spaces.  Below is the SQL.  I've found many resources on syntax, I'm just not grasping how to trim the @SearchText variable.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  The @SearchText variable is used as a parameter in SSRS.  Thank you

```
DECLARE @SearchText varchar(30)

select  Q.STATUS_EFF_DATE as DISP_DATE,
        Q.EXPIRATION_DATE as EXP_DATE,
        Q.STATUS as DISPOSITION,
        QL.PART_ID,
        QL.DESCRIPTION,
        QL.CUSTOMER_PART_ID,
        Q.NAME as CUST_NAME,
        Q.CUSTOMER_ID as CUST_ID,
        Q.ID as QUOTE_ID,
        QP.UNIT_PRICE,
        QP.QTY

from    Quote_LINE QL inner join QUote Q
         on QL.QUOTE_ID = Q.ID
        inner join QUOTE_PRICE QP
         on QP.QUOTE_ID = Q.ID
            and QP.QUOTE_LINE_NO = QL.LINE_NO

where   QL.PART_ID like '%' +@SearchText +'%'
        or QL.DESCRIPTION like '%' +@SearchText +'%'
        or QL.CUSTOMER_PART_ID like '%' +@SearchText +'%'
```

Comment: Use `LTRIM(RTRIM(@SearchText))`

Answer (score 0):

Use `LTRIM` to remove the `leading` space and use `RTRIM` to remove the `trailing` space.

```
where   QL.PART_ID like '%' +LTRIM(RTRIM(@SearchText)) +'%'
        or QL.DESCRIPTION like '%' +LTRIM(RTRIM(@SearchText)) +'%'
        or QL.CUSTOMER_PART_ID like '%' +LTRIM(RTRIM(@SearchText)) +'%'
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the help, I made that way to hard.